# How to display grouped list of values in Xamarin?

Tags: list, xamarin

I am trying to display grouped list of songs, which I get from server. Songs are grouped in sets according to their first letter. I've created two classes in this purpose SongSet and Song.

```
 public class SongSet
    {
        public string FirstCharacter { get; set; }
        public List<Song> ListOfSongs { get; set; } = new List<Song>(); 
       
        public SongSet(string firstChar)
        {
            this.FirstCharacter = firstChar;
        }
    }
```

```
   public class Song
    {
        public string SongTitle { get; set; }
        public Song(string title)
        {
            this.SongTitle = title;
        }
    }
```

After received list from server I put it to list of SongSet objects.

```
public static List<SongSet> ListOfSongsFromServer { get; set; } = new List<SongSet>();
```

And here my code to display a whole list.

```
 ListView listView = new ListView
            {
                IsGroupingEnabled = true,
                GroupDisplayBinding = new Binding("FirstCharacter"),
                ItemsSource = PlayerPageVM.ListOfSongsFromServer,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label titleLabel = new Label();
                    titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "SongTitle");
                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            Children =
                            {
                                new StackLayout
                                {
                                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
                                    Spacing=0,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                         titleLabel
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    };
                })

            };
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    listView
                }
            };
```

After build application I've received only list with first letters but without song titles uder them. Can anyone help me how to achievie this?

[image]

Comment: have you read the docs on grouped ListView and looked at their examples of structuring the data?

Comment: Yes, it's the first thing what I've done. I've read docs and other questions from this forum but now i don't know what should I change to get result what i want.

Comment: your grouped data should inherit from List<T> like in the docs.  You also do not show how you are populating your data so there may be issues there also

Comment: Problem was in lack of inheritance. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to display grouped list of songs, you could use **[CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping#example)**. Because it provides the easy way to show Group data.

Display grouped data:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                IsGrouped="true">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10">
                ...
                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And the problem of mode data could refer to document to make `SongSet` inherit from `Lsit<Song>` to generate a grouped data.

```
public class SongSet :  List<Song>
{
    public string FirstCharacter { get; set; }
   
    public SongSet(string firstChar,List<Song> ListOfSongs): base(ListOfSongs)
    {
        this.FirstCharacter = firstChar;
    }
}
```